# Ellipsize not working for textView inside custom listView

Tags: xml, android, textview

I have a listView with custom objects defined by the xml-layout below. I want the textView with id "info" to be ellipsized on a single line, and I've tried using the attributes

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

without success.

If I set the layout_width to a fixed width like e.g.

```
android:layout_width="100px"
```

the text is truncated fine. But for portability reasons this is not an acceptable solution.

Can you spot the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="5px"
>
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/destination"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="22dp"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
/>

<TextView  
android:id="@+id/date"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="15dp"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
/>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/info_table"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
android:paddingTop="10px" 
>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver_label"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5px"
            android:text="@string/driver_label" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passenger_label"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5px"
            android:text="@string/passenger_label" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passengers" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_label"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5px" 
            android:text="@string/info_label"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ellipsize is broken (go [vote on the bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882), especially since they claim it's not reproducible) so you have to use a minor hack. Use:

```
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
```

on anything you want to ellipsize. Also, don't use `singleLine`, it's been deprecated.

**UPDATE:**

On closer inspection, the problem you're having is that your table is extending off the right side of the screen. Changing your `TableLayout` definition to:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/info_table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:shrinkColumns="1">
```

should fix that problem, then do what I said above to ellipsize your `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Could it have something to do with the tableLayout?

Comment: NP... also, WRT the TableLayout definition: You only need to declare `xmlns:android` on the very first XML element.

Comment: This work-around is not working for me. I have a ListView, each item in the list has multiple text views in a TableLayout. When I added inputType='text' to the text view that can grow long, I can no longer select items from the list. Plus, I still did not see the ellipses. I did vote for the bug but it is closed and not reproducible. Perhaps a new bug report can be created. Any other ideas?

Comment: I agree, this did not work for me. TextView grew long, offset other parts of the horizontal linear layout it was in. Is this attribute dependent on some specific variable. I ended up setting android:maxLength="x" and that trimmed the text, without the elipsis

Comment: Since when is android:singleLine depreciated? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: @Samuel see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli The constant singleLine has been deprecated, the method TextView.setSingleLine() is still valid.

Comment: What I found is though Android Studio says `android:singleLine` is deprecated, it still needs for `android:ellipsize` to work

Answer (score 40):

Without using deprecated properties, the following lines work great for me

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:lines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

ref http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882#c9

Comment: Even without lines, ellipsize seems to be working only with the scrollHorizontally setting.

Comment: It will not work with Android 4.0. Use istead of code above: `android:ellipsize="end" 
android:SingleLine="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"`

Comment: Android Studio says android:singleLine is deprecated, it still needs for android:ellipsize to work

Answer (score 7):

I had the same results as Steve:

android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:lines="1"

works perfectly

Answer (score 4):

try...

i.e.

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:focusable="true" android:marqueeRepeatLimit="num|marquee_forever"
android:lines="1" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

as marquee only works when view is selected or focused according to the comment#2 on http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5364

Comment: I personally found that `android:ellipsize="marquee" android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:lines="1" ` was all you needed.

Answer (score 1):

After checking out these 3 issues(closed & re-opened) and previous posts, I think the key is to wrap up TextView with a outer LinearLayout(or any other layout you are using), and set the "**layout_width**" of outer layout width a little bit **SMALLER** than the text length contained in the TextView. Seems has to **LIMIT** the width to make the "android:ellipsize" behave properly.

Follow the tip in [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882#c39), after adding all these attributes for hacking, I also set the layout_width of outer LinearLayout to 240dp for example:

```
<Linearlayout
  android:layout_width="240dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ...>

    <TextView
     ....
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:lines="1"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:text="this is a text which length should be longer than 240dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Than I can successfully make the end of TextView displaying "...", not very acceptable but it works! And I think it works whether used in regular TextView or a TextView in a List Adapter.

Here's my screenshot for the result!

[image: hope it helps ^^]

Ref of those 3 issues:

[issue 882](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882)

[issue 10554](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10554)

[issue 31229](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31229)

Comment: I have added the code that works for me in the issue 882 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882 . Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you put TextView inside a custom ViewGroup you created, make sure to measure it again if you changed the dimension after the measurement.

E.g., I calculated the new dimension in onLayout. Before you call child.layout, call

```
measureChild(child,
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhere this attributes

```
<TextView ...
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

it work fine for me (Android 1.5)

Comment: singleLine is deprecated in 1.5

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment... can't find it in the docs but in the XML layout viewer of Eclipse it says that android:singleLine is depreciated and to use multiLine instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me these attribute worked. I tested on API 8 and onwards

In XML

```
<TextView
 ....
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
 android:ellipsize="end"
 ....
/>
```

Programmatically

```
setMaxLines(1);
setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

Comment: Version as in OS is 4.4.2. Component is a parent listview and the target TextView is a title of the item in the List .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in recycler view card. I have resolved this by adding following code:

```
    <TextView
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
```