# textView marquee

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to put a textView in  homescreen, and I need the marquee effect

```
public class MainWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
int a;
RemoteViews remoteViews;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
ComponentName thisWidget;

String[] s={"woddfdfdfdfdfdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff","dd","ddd","ffff"};
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new WlanTimer(context, appWidgetManager), 100, 50000);
}

private class WlanTimer extends TimerTask {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
        ComponentName thisWidget;

public WlanTimer(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {

        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.marketwidget_main);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MainWidget.class);
}

@Override
public void run() {
a=(int) (Math.random()*3);                            
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.TextView_marketwidget_main_marketmessage,s[a]);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
    }
}
}
```

If i use s[0] instead s[a], it does not run, only "woddfdf" shows up.

My textView xml is:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView_marketwidget_main_marketmessage"
    android:maxLines="1" android:focusable="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="20dip"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 5):

What I got from your question is, you want to show a scrolling marquee effect in TextView?
If I am right, do the following.

Set `android:ellipsize="marquee"` in `TextView` element in your layout file (XML). Then, in your Activity's `onCreate()` method, add the line `textView.setSelected(true);.`

Note: Replace the name textView with the name of your TextView.

Revert back for any query.

Comment: this method only in view of my app,the textView can marquee,but when i put the view as a appwidget in the home screen,it donot have marquee

Comment: This method scrolls the text only when the text in it is longer than its width. So try with more text.

Comment: i want a appwidget have marquee effect ,so i put the TextView as remoteView but it cannot get the effect

Comment: Have you tested it after putting more text in it?

Comment: Mudassir,i modify if but it cannot marqueer

Comment: Try adding android:singleLine="true" in the layout file.

Comment: i used  android:maxLines="1", i also use android:singleLine="true" but the result is same

Comment: @Mudassir  The user's original question was about a scrolling TextView in a homescreen widget.  Your solution only works in an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the properties android:ellipsize="marquee" of textview.
and hope this link would help you out if on using this property still not working:
[Ellipsize not working for textView inside custom listView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424276/ellipsize-not-working-for-textview-inside-custom-listview)

Comment: i modify my textView xml but ,iconnot get marqueer,it only "woddfdfdf"

Answer (score 0):

The minimum code you need to add in xml file is

```
<TextView
    .
    .
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
```

also do not forget to add this line in your `onCreate` method

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```