# Android: enabling text marquee when text is shorter than textview

Tags: android, marquee

Is there any way to enable text marquee when text is shorter than textview?

Answer (score 0):

Set the elipsize property in TextView to marquee in the xml file

> android:ellipsize="marquee"

and then create an object for the TextView in your onCreate method of your activity and set the setSelectedProperty to true

> textview1.setSelected(true)

[Source:Previous Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332819/textview-marquee)

Comment: Thanks but android:ellipsize="marquee" and setSelected(true) doesn't help.