# ScrollHorizontally workaround to ellipsize for textviews causing StackOverflowError in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have a textview that I want to have ellipses at the end if the text is longer than the space for the view. The TextView is enclosed in a FrameLayout, which is part of a horizontal LinearLayout with elements on either side of it (perhaps this is not the right way to approach it, but without the FrameLayout, the elements in the row after the text were not being placed at the end of the row, which is what I want). As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424276/ellipsize-not-working-for-textview-inside-custom-listview), I added `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` to my TextView and that does what I want. However, now when I open the layout file to the xml rather than the Graphical Layout in Eclipse, I get a popup that says

> Problem Occurred - java.lang.StackOverflowError

Error log has no further information on what's happening here. Note that this isn't when I run my code - I think this happens just when the project builds (which I've set to be automatic).

Anyone have any insight as to what's going on here, or whether the error is harmless? I'd like to still use scrollHorizontally since otherwise ellipsize doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have you upgraded to the latest version of the Android Eclipse plugin that came out a few days ago? It made a large number of bug fixes

Comment: I hadn't, thanks for that. However, that didn't fix this issue. I'm still getting the same StackOverflowError

Comment: suggested tag "eclipse" since it might be IDE-related