# Strange issue with android:ellipsize="end"

Tags: android-layout, android

I am using **android:ellipsize="end"** in android xml file, & surprisingly I am not getting the layout that I want, the 3 dots(...) are showing but after that dots there is another word truncated. Also this is a "not-always" behavior, check the ListView attached, sometimes, the behavior is normal & sometimes not.

Here's the screenshot of the layout from my device,

[image]

I don't have any idea why this is happening. Here's my xml file, having problem with the **tv_news_content** TextView -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@color/white" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_next_tier"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_news_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_next_tier"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="News Title"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_news_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_news_title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_news_title"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_next_tier"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="News Contents"
    android:textColor="@color/black_light"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_news_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

To make things clear, **tv_news_title** is the topmost bold TextView, & **iv_next_tier** is the small arrow-type ImageView at the right. & **tv_news_content** is the TextView that I am facing problem with.

Any solution why I am not getting desired output? Desired output means the always normal behaviour - I want those 3 dots at the end of second line of **tv_news_content** TextView, not before a truncated word.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What is iv_next_tier ? I think it will help us better to see the entire xml or at least the RelativeLayout content..

Comment: What happens if you change `maxLines="2"` to `lines="2"`?

Comment: @Cata, I mentioned already iv_next_tier is the small arrow-type ImageView, that you see at the right corner of the screenshot. I am updating the xml, will post full xml in a minute.

Comment: @KenWolf, I get same result :-(

Comment: @Khobaib Same problem. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi @dilettante sorry for late reply, I somehow missed it. I resolved this issue somehow (I didn't find any proper solution, so did some hack).
I replied in RuAware's post about my findings. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the text for the textview make sure the text is not greater than 750 characters so use txt = theText.substring(0, 750) or something like that before calling settext. This works on the emulator with your feed. and should be enough characters for a 10inch tablet too

Comment: I tried with trial & error, 750 doesn't work but when I make the text of 300 length at most, then it works for both item #3 & #4. When I used 500, it worked for #3 but not #4.
I am wondering what's the reason behind it. Can you give me some light?

Comment: did u find any proper solution as this solution is not proper @Khobaib

Comment: no I didn't find any proper solution yet @ChiragShah

Comment: I've found that 500 is the lucky number with my situation.

Answer (score 14):

Finally found what was causing this issue in my app!!

While RuAware's answer led me on the right path, I found that it didn't fix the problem for all of my text blocks. Given that it worked for some, I felt it was clearly due to some malicious character. So I went through one broken text block and just started removing characters until it stopped breaking.

It turns out it was the new line character `'\n'` that was causing it. Even if the new line was after the ellipsize, the new line character was [inconsistently] causing this problem as long as it was somewhere within the string.

The issue is solved by doing something similar to the following before setting the text to your view:

```
text = text.replace('\n',' ');
```

Comment: Cool, let me know how it goes. The problem you responded with in RuAware's answer is probably because of the varying position of new lines in your strings

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763689/1897423). There is a custom EllipsizingTextView which solves ellipsizing problem for multiline view. However it may solve you problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem when displaying a String containing html formatted text.

Removing all html tags with `myText.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")` solved the problem.

You can also remove html tags using `Html.fromHtml(myText).toString()`, but notice that you must use **.toString()** and **not apply the fromHtml output directly to the TextView**. If some special characters are html encoded (&amp, &gt, &lt...) you can safely apply again Html.fromHtml() to the final String.

Answer (score -1):

i used :

```
if (myModel.mDataText().length() > 150) {
    mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myModel.mDataText().substring(0, 150) + "..."));
} else {
    mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myModel.mDataText() + "..."));
}
```

Comment: sorry, I told myself the way I used

Comment: I find android:singleLine="true" but i dont test!! you can checked this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768977/text-does-not-ellipsize

Comment: @RahilTaavighi, I don't want it single line. I want it 2 liner at most.

Comment: Add these lines to textview tag: android:ellipsize="marquee" 
 android:singleLine="false" 
 android:maxLines="2"