# Android TextView ellipsize error with Html Text

Tags: android, textview

I have some problem with ellipsize in TextView.

Here is html string:

```
final String str = "His followed carriage proposal entrance <br/>directly had elegance. Greater for cottage gay parties natural. Remaining he furniture on he discourse suspected perpetual. <br/>Power dried her taken place day ought the. Four and our ham west miss."
```

I create 2 textview(tv_test_html, tv_test_normal).

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_test_html"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Hello"
            />
<TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_test_normal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Hello"
            />
```

In code I set:

```
 final TextView tvTestHtml = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_test_html);
 final TextView tvTestNormal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_test_normal);
 tvTestHtml.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
 tvTestNormal.setText(str);
```

When I run application:

[image: result]

You can see "..." is error when I use Html.fromHtml(...);

So how do I fix it ?

**Thanks in advance !**

[I just update image]

Comment: There's something wrong with the image you posted, I can't see it. Can you upload it somewhere else?

Comment: Please update your question .Image not showing

Comment: Please try this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8s-G0RvKL-3X1pZZEtDMjRpVXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17131294/2504200

Comment: Thanks so much ! Problem is "\n" character. So I need custom TextView :|

Answer (score 0):

replace string with it : `His followed carriage proposal entrance <br>directly had elegance. Greater for cottage gay parties natural. Remaining he furniture on he discourse suspected perpetual. <br>Power dried her taken place day ought the. Four and our ham west miss.`

Comment: is replace the <br/> with <br>

Comment: It's still not working for me. I think problem is WIDTH of textview.