# TextView does not ellipsize

Tags: android

I have checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173776/ellipsize-not-working-properly-for-a-multiline-textview-with-an-arbitrary-maximu#) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768977/text-does-not-ellipsize) but still could not figure out why my ellipsize still doesn't work.

I use the following `CardView` inside a `RecyclerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginVertical="2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/food_image_card"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/food_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_image_place_holder" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/food_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/food_name_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/food_image_card"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/food_image_card">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Food Name"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/liked_image"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_undo_like" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tag_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginVertical="2dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tag_header"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tag_header" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tag_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="Placeholder" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/note_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginVertical="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/note_header"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/note_header" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/note_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:text="Placeholder" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Although `tag_content` and `note_content` look ellipsized in Android Studio (1st image), they actually don't ellipsize on my cell phone (first item on 2nd image). Any ideas why?

I think there is nothing wrong with the xml. The reason why it does not ellipsize is I changed the text in my adapter.

This is my project [website](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu) and the posted code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/view_listed_food_search.xml) and will be used in this [adapter](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/Adapters/SearchFoodListAdapter.java)

[image: Android Studio][image: My Cell Phone]

Answer (score 0):

You have force TextView `note_content` to have 3 lines, so it will not ellipsized if content can be fit in 3 lines.

```
 <TextView
          android:id="@+id/note_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:ellipsize="start"
          android:maxLines="3"
          android:text="Placeholder" />
```

If you change `android:maxLines="1"` text will be ellipsized.

Comment: Sorry but `note_content` actually has more than 3 lines. Same for `tag_content`. It has content more than one line but it doesn't ellipsize.

Comment: Please disregard the second item on second image. I implemented that ... maunally.

Comment: hmm can it be the language, could you try to put spaces among the word, could you try to put `android:maxWidth = "20sp` on tag_content ...

Comment: It doesn't work. My cell phone still directly cuts off the text.