# EditText automatically to the latest char?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I want create simple calculator for android, and having problem with displaying long equations. Everything is OK (one line, horizontal scrolling), but I don't see end of line (always see start of line). Would it be possible to scroll it automatically to the latest character?

```
Example:

Hello there
...lo there
   --------
```

-

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="0." />
```

Image: [SimpleCalc image](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-CxoJiyIC0v0/UuP4yNIvRoI/AAAAAAAAA4k/J0rRSNOP67E/w536-h893-no/Screenshot_2014-01-25-17-11-34.png)

Comment: You have set `ellipsize="end"`.  Is that your intention?  Your example shows ellipsis at the start.

Comment: Even with `ellipsize="start"` there is no diference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly :D only code is much more longer. If is there any other way to set this in xml please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The "official" way of doing that is (as suggested in the comments), via the `ellipsize` attribute set to `end`. If it's not working, it might be due this attribute is a bit tricky, meaning that it has some circumstances to be happening in order to work (like for example, `singleLine=true`).

You might want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424276/ellipsize-not-working-for-textview-inside-custom-listview), it helped me when I had this issue.